# Not able to login to admin after SSL setup

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, ssl

I have an issue with login to my admin panel after installing an SSL certificate.

I get the error message :

> You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.

I tried to set `web/secure/use_in_frontend` and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` to 0 but didnt work
I also tried :

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>
```

Nothing worked

Any help?

Comment: The error you've posted sometimes points to an incorrect login (username/password). Are you sure you're using the right details to login? It might be worth trying to setup a new user to test with as well.

Comment: how can I setup a user from CLI ?

Comment: yes I am sure about my detaisl

Comment: `php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='testing' --admin-password='testing123' --admin-email='testing@testing.com' --admin-firstname='Test' --admin-lastname='Test'` Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you , that worked for me, I think the problem was create a customer with same email as admin.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I've added in my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.

Usually points to an issue with the user you're trying to sign in with, if you're sure that the details you are using to login are correct then you can try unlocking the user with:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock
```

Or, creating a new user via CLI with:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='testing' --admin-password='testing123' --admin-email='testing@testing.com' --admin-firstname='Test' --admin-lastname='Test'
```